# Django formsets of dynamic forms

Tags: python, django, formset

I have several arbitrary datastructures that I want to be filled by a user and I think the django formsets are the most suitable way to deal with it, thanks to prefixes, but I'm not sure.

Let's say I always have an initial data whose keys and values can vary depending on the situation, but for this example I will use:

```
fields = {
  "first"  : forms.IntegerField(),
  "second" : forms.CharField()
}
```

I have the following class to create forms dynamically:

```
class fieldsForm (forms.Form):
   pass
```

Thus, I create a class dynamically:

```
DynamicForm = type('DynamicForm', (fieldsForm,), fields)
```

Then, I create a formset and I instantiate it:

```
dynamicFormSet = forms.formset_factory(DynamicMsgForm)
formset = dynamicFormSet()
```

The key is I can have extra field dicts that I want to handle on the same formset giving to each dict form instance an index, for example:

```
another = {
  "first"  : forms.IntegerField(),
  "second" : forms.CharField(),
  "third"  : forms.IntegerField()
}
```

Finally, I create the class dynamically again, I instantiate it and I try to include it to the previous formset instance:

```
DynamicForm = type('DynamicForm', (fieldsForm,), another)
anotherFormInstance = DynamicForm()
formset.add_fields(form=anotherFormInstance, index=1)
```

My problem is that the formset is not being updated with the "another" form instance, I think I've misundertood formsets. I expect to distinguish between the form fields by its prefix thanks to the setted index while appending the forms, as the keys can be repeated.

Note: I'm working with classes of a composite pattern, the first datastructure is a composite that contain leaves, but that can contain one or more composites too which can only contain leaves, not another composite.

Comment: `add_fields` is a method that is used to add fields to form **when it is created** (when you try to access i-th form in formset, it will call multiple methods to instantiate and modify form instance adding DELETE, order, etc.; `form` argument is a form instance, not a class). You can subclass `BaseFormSet`, overriding `forms` property or `_construct_form` (or some more specific method maybe), and pass it it `formset_factory`. However, if what you need is to have multiple __different__ forms, I'd rather suggest instantiating them directly with different prefixes.

Comment: Also you can look at [`formsets` source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/forms/formsets.py), it's fairly concise and understandable.

Comment: @SUTerliakov thank you for your advices. I will then create a list of different forms instances, instantiating them with different auto_id to distinguish them.